# MapReduce on two Collections using MongoDB and C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have two collections with the following details:

### Comments

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("521588ccb5d44d23aca151a2"), "UserId" : "5215862eb5d44d23aca1519d", "Comment" : "hello" }
{"_id" : ObjectId("521588ccb5d44d23aca151a3"), "UserId" : "5215862eb5d44d23aca1519e", "Comment" : "this is cool" }
```

"Comment" : "hello" }
    {"_id" : ObjectId("521588ccb5d44d23aca151a4"), "UserId" : "5215862eb5d44d23aca1519e", "Comment" : "I like mongo" }

### User

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5215862eb5d44d23aca1519d"), "Nickname" : "Jane"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5215862eb5d44d23aca1519e"), "Nickname" : "Jon"}
```

How would I achieve the following using MapReduce (and is it the best for the task at hand)? This collection could ideally also be very large. i.e. hundreds of thousands or millions.

```
{ "UserId" : "5215862eb5d44d23aca1519d", "Comment": "Hello", "Nickname" : "Jane"}
{ "UserId" : "5215862eb5d44d23aca1519e", "Comment": "this is cool", "Nickname" : "Jon"}
{ "UserId" : "5215862eb5d44d23aca1519e", "Comment": "I like Mongo", "Nickname" : "Jon"}
```

Bote: I am using MongoDB with the .NET C# drivers.

Answer (score 1):

MapReduce is not a good tool for this task, because a MapReduce query is always performed on a single collection. You would have to perform a MapReduce on one collection, and in the mapping function read from the other. But [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/) explicitely warns that you shouldn't do this: *"The reduce function should not access the database, even to perform read operations"*.

MongoDB in general is not designed for performing JOIN-operations.

What you can do:

**Solution A:** Perform the JOIN on the application layer. First query the comment collection and then use the results to query the user collection in a second query.

**Solution B:** Store a copy of the authors nickname in the comment documents so you don't have to query the user collection (In document-oriented databases, redundancies aren't as evil as in relational databases).